# Why is multi-threading of matrix calculation not faster than single-core?

Tags: c++, multithreading, matrix

this is my first time using multi-threading to speed up a heavy calculation.

Background: The idea is to calculate a Kernel Covariance matrix, by reading a list of 3D points `x_test` and calculating the corresponding matrix, which has dimensions `x_test.size()` x `x_test.size()`.

I already sped up the calculations by only calculating the lower triangluar matrix. Since all the calculations are independent from each other I tried to speed up the process (`x_test.size() = 27000` in my case) by splitting the calculations of the matrix entries row-wise, assigning a range of rows to each thread.

*On a single core the calculations took about 280 seconds each time, on 4 cores it took 270-290 seconds.*

**main.cpp**

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double sigma0sq = 1;
    double lengthScale [] = {0.7633, 0.6937, 3.3307e+07};
    
    const std::vector<std::vector<double>> x_test = parse2DCsvFile(inputPath);
    
    /* Finding data slices of similar size */
    //This piece of code works, each thread is assigned roughly the same number of matrix entries
    int numElements = x_test.size()*x_test.size()/2;
    const int numThreads = 4;
    int elemsPerThread = numElements / numThreads;
    std::vector<int> indices;

    int j = 0;
    for(std::size_t i=1; i<x_test.size()+1; ++i){
        int prod = i*(i+1)/2 - j*(j+1)/2;
        if (prod > elemsPerThread) {
            i--;
            j = i;
            indices.push_back(i);
            if(indices.size() == numThreads-1)
                break;
        }
    }
    indices.insert(indices.begin(), 0);
    indices.push_back(x_test.size());

    /* Spreding calculations to multiple threads */
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for(std::size_t i = 1; i < indices.size(); ++i){
        threads.push_back(std::thread(calculateKMatrixCpp, x_test, lengthScale, sigma0sq, i, indices.at(i-1), indices.at(i)));
    }

    for(auto & th: threads){
        th.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, each thread performs the following calculations on the data assigned to it:

```cpp
void calculateKMatrixCpp(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> xtest, double lengthScale[], double sigma0sq, int threadCounter, int start, int stop){
    char buffer[8192];

    std::ofstream out("lower_half_matrix_" + std::to_string(threadCounter) +".csv");
    out.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, 8196);

    for(int i = start; i < stop; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < i+1; ++j){
            double kij = seKernel(xtest.at(i), xtest.at(j), lengthScale, sigma0sq);
            if (j!=0)
                out << ',';
            out << kij;
        }
        if(i!=xtest.size()-1 )
            out << '\n';
    }
    out.close();
}
```

and

```cpp
double seKernel(const std::vector<double> x1,const std::vector<double> x2, double lengthScale[], double sigma0sq) {
    double sum(0);
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<x1.size();i++){
        sum += pow((x1.at(i)-x2.at(i))/lengthScale[i],2);
    }
    return sigma0sq*exp(-0.5*sum);
}
```

**Aspects I considered**

- locking by simultaneous access to data vector -> I don't pass a reference to the threads, but a copy of the data. I know this is not optimal in terms of RAM usage, but as far as I know this should prevent simultaneous data access since every thread has its own copy
- Output -> every thread writes its part of the lower triangular matrix to its own file. My task manager doesn't indicate a full SSD utilization in the slightest

**Compiler and machine**

- Windows 11
- GNU GCC Compiler
- Code::Blocks (although I don't think that should be of importance)

Comment: Why are you copying all the vectors in `seKernel`? Are you sure you the computation was actually the bottleneck and not for example the memory?

Comment: "this shoul prevent simultaneous data access" - why do you want to prevent that? You are only reading data, there is no data race.

Comment: @Eljay OP mentions "280 seconds" of single-thread processing time, I don't think the overhead from creating 4 threads is an issue.

Comment: @Nelfeal The threads might try to read the same data point at the same time

Comment: Re, "every thread writes...to its own file."  Have you measureed how much of its time your program spends reading and writing files and compared that to how much time it spends doing calculations? Using multiple threads can speed up calculations because your computer has multiple CPUs, each with its own memory cache; but if you're using a typical desktop or laptop computer, then there's only one file store, and multi-threading will not speed up access to it.

Comment: @Solomon Slow I think I will do that next, thank you. I thought SSD speed utilization below 10% meant that this was not the bottleneck, but I'm using a normal laptop computer.

Comment: @blockchain187 So? Many threads can read the same constant data at the same time, it's not an issue.

Comment: I am trying to understand, you have vector of 27,000 vectors of 3 elements each? Then in each thread you create a copy of this fragmemted piece of memory for no reason. And for each pair of these small vectors in each thread you create two additional copies just to compute vector length difference? Have you heard about memory fragmentation issues? Also while memory allocation is thread safe, it is a heavy operation and I doubt that it can be parallelised.

Comment: @ALX23z that is mostly correct. What I'm doing here is calculating the Kernel covariance matrix for a Gaussian process. (see http://evelinag.com/Ariadne/covarianceFunctions.html) This matrix contains information about the "similarity" between two data points, that's why often the distance is used. But as you have pointed out, passing a copy to the `seKernel` function is not neccessary, I just changed it.

Comment: @Nelfeal Ah, I thought it might cause a locking effect, where each thread waits for the others to finish reading the requested memory. Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, passing references instead of vector copies does not speed up the program.

Comment: @blockchain187 There is no locking unless you specify there should be one (by using mutexes). In any case, even if passing references doesn't speed up the program, it's still a good start toward a speed-up. Can you provide sample data or a way to generate similar data? Do random points within a unit cube work?

Comment: @Nelfeal It should work. The actual data are equidistant points from the 3D space [0.35,0.85]x[0.34,0.78]x[2.6779e+07
,4.1526e+07]. 30 points in every dimension ad up to 27,000 points.

Comment: @blockchain187 what I am pointing out, is that you do it very inefficiently. Storing the data in such fragmented way is an excellent way to slow down the code. You, have a lot of unnecessary data allocations and storing each vector in a dynamically allocated data is very inefficient for reading. It is both faster for loading and for compiler optimizations if you were to store the elements in a static array `std::array<double,3>`. Also copying the whole big vector in each thread is unnecessary - just pass a reference/pointer. Check `std::ref` to see how to pass arguments by ref into a thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many details that can be improved in your code, but I think the two biggest issues are:

- using vectors or vectors, which leads to fragmented data;
- writing each piece of data to file as soon as its value is computed.

The first point is easy to fix: use something like `std::vector<std::array<double, 3>>`. In the code below I use an alias to make it more readable:

```
using Point3D = std::array<double, 3>;
std::vector<Point3D> x_test;
```

The second point is slightly harder to address. I assume you wanted to write to the disk inside each thread because you couldn't manage to write to a shared buffer that you could then write to a file.

Here is a way to do exactly that:

```
void calculateKMatrixCpp(
    std::vector<Point3D> const& xtest, Point3D const& lengthScale, double sigma0sq,
    int threadCounter, int start, int stop, std::vector<double>& kMatrix
) {
    // ...
    double& kij = kMatrix[i * xtest.size() + j];
    kij = seKernel(xtest[i], xtest[j], lengthScale, sigma0sq);
    // ...
}
// ...
threads.push_back(std::thread(
    calculateKMatrixCpp, x_test, lengthScale, sigma0sq,
    i, indices[i-1], indices[i], std::ref(kMatrix)
));
```

Here, `kMatrix` is the shared buffer and represents the whole matrix you are trying to compute. You need to pass it to the thread via `std::ref`. Each thread will write to a different location in that buffer, so there is no need for any mutex or other synchronization.

Once you make these changes and try to write `kMatrix` to the disk, you will realize that this is the part that takes the most time, *by far*.

Below is the full code I tried on my machine, and the computation time was about 2 seconds whereas the writing-to-file part took 300 seconds! No amount of multithreading can speed that up.

If you truly want to write all that data to the disk, you may have some luck with [file mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Computing the exact size needed should be easy enough if all values have the same number of digits, and it looks like you could write the values with multithreading. I have never done anything like that, so I can't really say much more about it, but it looks to me like the fastest way to write multiple gigabytes of memory to the disk.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>

using Point3D = std::array<double, 3>;

auto generateSampleData() -> std::vector<Point3D> {
    static std::minstd_rand g(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> d(-1.0, 1.0);

    std::vector<Point3D> data;
    data.reserve(27000);
    for (auto i = 0; i < 27000; ++i) {
        data.push_back({ d(g), d(g), d(g) });
    }
    return data;
}

double seKernel(Point3D const& x1, Point3D const& x2, Point3D const& lengthScale, double sigma0sq) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (auto i = 0u; i < 3u; ++i) {
        double distance = (x1[i] - x2[i]) / lengthScale[i];
        sum += distance*distance;
    }
    return sigma0sq * std::exp(-0.5*sum);
}

void calculateKMatrixCpp(std::vector<Point3D> const& xtest, Point3D const& lengthScale, double sigma0sq, int threadCounter, int start, int stop, std::vector<double>& kMatrix) {
    std::cout << "start of thread " << threadCounter << "\n" << std::flush;
    for(int i = start; i < stop; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i+1; ++j) {
            double& kij = kMatrix[i * xtest.size() + j];
            kij = seKernel(xtest[i], xtest[j], lengthScale, sigma0sq);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "end of thread " << threadCounter << "\n" << std::flush;
}

int main() {
    double sigma0sq = 1;
    Point3D lengthScale = {0.7633, 0.6937, 3.3307e+07};

    const std::vector<Point3D> x_test = generateSampleData();

    /* Finding data slices of similar size */
    //This piece of code works, each thread is assigned roughly the same number of matrix entries
    int numElements = x_test.size()*x_test.size()/2;
    const int numThreads = 4;
    int elemsPerThread = numElements / numThreads;
    std::vector<int> indices;

    int j = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 1; i < x_test.size()+1; ++i){
        int prod = i*(i+1)/2 - j*(j+1)/2;
        if (prod > elemsPerThread) {
            i--;
            j = i;
            indices.push_back(i);
            if(indices.size() == numThreads-1)
                break;
        }
    }
    indices.insert(indices.begin(), 0);
    indices.push_back(x_test.size());

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::vector<double> kMatrix(x_test.size() * x_test.size(), 0.0);

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < indices.size(); ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(calculateKMatrixCpp, x_test, lengthScale, sigma0sq, i, indices[i - 1], indices[i], std::ref(kMatrix)));
    }

    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration<double>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << "computation time: " << elapsed_seconds << "s" << std::endl;


    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    constexpr int buffer_size = 131072;
    char buffer[buffer_size];
    std::ofstream out("matrix.csv");
    out.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, buffer_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < x_test.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j) {
            if (j != 0) {
                out << ',';
            }
            out << kMatrix[i * x_test.size() + j];
        }

        if (i != x_test.size() - 1) {
            out << '\n';
        }
    }
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration<double>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << "writing time: " << elapsed_seconds << "s" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think one of main issues that slowdown the code is reliance on the operator `<<` of `ostream`. Were you to print the data first into a `std::vector<char>` via `format_to` (perhaps even in a parallelized way by making multiple vectors of char) and then dump it into file, it'd be like 50 to 100 times faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The main reason why I stream the data directly into an output stream is, that the goal was to scale the process up to matrices of sizes 1 Mio. x 1 Mio. and bigger. My RAM would just capitulate.

Comment: @ALX23z I tried using a `std::stringstream` as an intermediary, it didn't speed up at all. I don't know if `std::vector<char>` and `format_to` would change anything.

Comment: The problem is the virtualization of the calls and some unnecessary memory calls that ensure thread-safety. `stringstream` is the same as `ofstream` in this regard. `format_to/format` do not have such issues.

Comment: Basically, it is slow not because writing to file takes a lot of time - what takes time is formatting the data via `ostream`. I am sure you've heard that `char_conv` is hella faster than streams.

Comment: @ALX23z I guess so. I'm not familiar enough with these things, but you're welcome to write an answer.

Comment: @Nelfeal I've written a C++20 version via `std::format/format_to` it takes 70 on a single thread and around 30 seconds on 3 threads - at least on my system. The `ofstream` version would take me around 250 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Okey I've wrote implementation with optimized formatting.

By using @Nelfeal code it was taking on my system around 250 seconds for the run to complete with write time taking the most by far. Or rather `std::ofstream` formatting taking most of the time.

I've written a C++20 version via `std::format_to/format`. It is a multi-threaded version that takes around 25-40 seconds to complete all the computations, formatting, and writing. If run in a single thread, it takes on my system around 70 seconds. Same performance should be achievable via `fmt` library on C++11/14/17.

Here is the code:

```
import <vector>;
import <thread>;
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
import <cmath>;
import <array>;
import <random>;
import <fstream>;
import <chrono>;
import <format>;
import <filesystem>;

using Point3D = std::array<double, 3>;

auto generateSampleData(Point3D scale) -> std::vector<Point3D>
{
    static std::minstd_rand g(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> d(-1.0, 1.0);

    std::vector<Point3D> data;
    data.reserve(27000);
    for (auto i = 0; i < 27000; ++i)
    {
        data.push_back({ d(g)* scale[0], d(g)* scale[1], d(g)* scale[2] });
    }
    return data;
}

double seKernel(Point3D const& x1, Point3D const& x2, Point3D const& lengthScale, double sigma0sq) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (auto i = 0u; i < 3u; ++i) {
        double distance = (x1[i] - x2[i]) / lengthScale[i];
        sum += distance * distance;
    }
    return sigma0sq * std::exp(-0.5 * sum);
}

void calculateKMatrixCpp(std::vector<Point3D> const& xtest, Point3D lengthScale, double sigma0sq, int threadCounter, int start, int stop, std::filesystem::path localPath) 
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    buffer.reserve(15'000);

    std::ofstream out(localPath);

    std::cout << std::format("starting thread {}: from {} to {}\n"sv, threadCounter, start, stop);

    for (int i = start; i < stop; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) 
        {
            double kij = seKernel(xtest[i], xtest[j], lengthScale, sigma0sq);
            std::format_to(std::back_inserter(buffer), "{:.6g}, "sv, kij);
        }

        double kii = seKernel(xtest[i], xtest[i], lengthScale, sigma0sq);
        std::format_to(std::back_inserter(buffer), "{:.6g}\n"sv, kii);

        out.write(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
        buffer.clear();
    }
}

int main() {
    double sigma0sq = 1;
    Point3D lengthScale = { 0.7633, 0.6937, 3.3307e+07 };

    const std::vector<Point3D> x_test = generateSampleData(lengthScale);

    /* Finding data slices of similar size */
    //This piece of code works, each thread is assigned roughly the same number of matrix entries
    int numElements = x_test.size() * (x_test.size()+1) / 2;
    const int numThreads = 3;
    int elemsPerThread = numElements / numThreads;
    std::vector<int> indices;

    int j = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < x_test.size() + 1; ++i) {
        int prod = i * (i + 1) / 2 - j * (j + 1) / 2;
        if (prod > elemsPerThread) {
            i--;
            j = i;
            indices.push_back(i);
            if (indices.size() == numThreads - 1)
                break;
        }
    }
    indices.insert(indices.begin(), 0);
    indices.push_back(x_test.size());

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;

    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < indices.size(); ++i) 
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(calculateKMatrixCpp, std::ref(x_test), lengthScale, sigma0sq, i, indices[i - 1], indices[i], std::format("./matrix_{}.csv"sv, i-1)));
    }

    for (auto& t : threads) 
    {
        t.join();
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration<double>(end - start);

    std::cout << std::format("total elapsed time: {}"sv, elapsed_seconds);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I used 6 digits of precision here as it is the default for `std::ofstream`. More digits means more writing time to disk and lower performance.